# Is this derivation of the Pythagorean identity correct?

Tags: trigonometry

Is the derivation of the following trigonometric identity correct?  I accept the conclusion is true and the author reached the correct equation, but look at the 2nd to last line of the page I scanned in (I put a small arrow at the beginning of that line).  It reads:

> But $a^2 = \sin^2(x)$, and $b^2 = \cos^2(x)$.

It should read:

> But $a^2 = \cos^2(x)$, and $b^2 = \sin^2(x)$.

If you look at the 4th and 5th lines from the bottom of the scanned in page it.  They are correct, but upon squaring the trig functions the author appears to have swapped around the $a^2$ and the $b^2$.  Am I right in this assertion of mine?

The book this came from is "Theta Mathematics" by David Barton, page 156 published by Pearson 2011.  This is not homework, I study maths for my own interest.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a typo in the book. You're right, $a$ and $b$ were swapped in that line.

Answer (score 1):

The derivation is correct up untill the swap at the end. Its good that you noticed it, shows you are truly understanding!

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Since the sine of an angle is always a scaled version of the side *opposite* the angle, you're as right as right could be.

This must have been a typographical error.